# How to disable react navigation's stack navigator transition?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

In React Native (iOS), [React navigation's stack navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html) has a default transition animation to move screens left or right based on the stack order. Is there any way to disable the transition animation?

Comment: Thanks for your good question.

Answer (score 89):

**React Navigation 6**

```js
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ animation: 'none' }}></Stack.Navigator>
```

**React Navigation 5**

```js
{/* Screen level */}
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen
      name="HomeScreen"
      component={HomeScreen}
      options={{
        animationEnabled: false,
      }}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>

{/* Whole navigation stack */}
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ animationEnabled: false }}></Stack.Navigator>
```

More options here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/

Comment: or to turn it off in the whole navigation stack: `<Stack.navigator screenOptions={{animationEnabled: false}}>`

Comment: If you're setting this on a per-screen basis, note that you need to disable `animationEnabled` on the screen you're navigating TO, not from. It can be a little bit confusing since a transition involves 2 screens.

Comment: This seems very limiting. I would rather be able to disable the animation a the time I'm navigating to the screen. For instance, if there's a screen I want to animate most of the time with a few edge case exceptions. It would be nice to just turn it off when I need to.

Comment: @Euroclydon37 you can enable it in the screen via [setOptions](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#setoptions)

Comment: @wobsoriano Ooooooo... I'll mess around with that. Thanks!

Comment: For react navigation v6, it's now `<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ animation: 'none' }}>`

Comment: @FlorentRoques THANK YOU. This needs to be higher. I thought I was going crazy. The docs on the website still reference animationEnabled.

Comment: In React Navigation 6 how can you disable it (or enable it) for specific screens?

Answer (score 17):

### React Navigation v6:

Use `screenOptions={{ animation: 'none' }}` on the Navigator to disable all animations inside the Navigator

or

use `options={{ animation: 'none' }}` on the Screen you wan't to navigate to without animation.

**Code Example:**

```
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ animation: 'none' }}>
  <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
  <Stack.Screen name="Store" options={{ animation: 'none' }} component={Store} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 8):

Hope it would help you. Please try as below.

```
const StackNavigatorConfig = {
  [...]
  transitionConfig : () => ({
    transitionSpec: {
      duration: 0,
      timing: Animated.timing,
      easing: Easing.step0,
      },
  }),
}

export const Navigator = StackNavigator(RouteConfiguration,StackNavigatorConfig)
```

Comment: Where are `Animated` and `Easing` imported from?

Answer (score 8):

You can disable transition animations with the `animationEnabled` navigation option. [Docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#animationenabled)

```js
defaultNavigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
  animationEnabled: false,
})
```

You may want to pass this in `navigationOptions` instead depending on your use case.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is a Boolean variable controls the transition animation. So we can't directly hide the animation.

But there is a variable controls the animation duration !

Try this~ ↓

```
const RootStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  // ...
}, {
  transitionConfig: () => ({
    transitionSpec: {
      duration: 0,  // Set the animation duration time as 0 !!
    },
  }),
});
```

Comment: unfortunatelly it still animated on fireing `navigation.goBack()`

Answer (score 5):

> Update for **react-native : 0.61.5**

We were able to turnoff the animations/transitions using the below props in navigationOptions.

```
animationEnabled:false,
transitionConfig: () => ({
  transitionSpec: {
    duration:0,
    timing: 0,
  },
})
```

Other relevant packages that we're using are:

- "react-navigation": "~4.0.10"
- "react-navigation-stack": "^2.1.0"
- "react-native-screens": "2.0.0-beta.2"

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `@react-navigation/native-stack` you can disable transition by using `animation` option of `Stack.Navigator` component.

```js
// create Stack component
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

// use Stack component in JSX
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ animation: 'none' }}>
    <Stack.Screen name={'Home'} component={Home} />
    <Stack.Screen name={'Page'} component={Page} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 2):

For my case, I'm disabling animation for home screen.

"react-navigation": "^4.3.9",

"react-navigation-stack": "^2.7.0",

```
const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
{
    SplashScreen: SplashScreen,
    MainScreen: {
        name: 'HomeScreen',
        screen: HomeScreen,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            animationEnabled: false,
            transitionConfig: () => ({
                transitionSpec: {
                    duration: 0,
                    timing: 0,
                },
            })
        }),
    },
},
{
    initialRouteName: 'SplashScreen',
    headerMode: 'none'
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In the newest version of react-native (in my case: )

```
"react-native": "0.60.5",
"react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
"react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
```

just put the following config:

```
transitionConfig: () => ({
  transitionSpec: {
    timing: Animated.timing,
  },
  screenInterpolator: () => {},
}),
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest answer:

```js
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
{/*        ||             ||
           \/             \/   */}
      animationEnabled: false
    }}
  >
    <Stack.Screen name="Landing" component={Landing}/>
    <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={Register}/>
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<Stack.Screen name='Timeline' component={Timeline} options={{ animation: 'none', headerShown: true, headerTitle: "Timeline" }} />
```

Just pass "animation as none" with options