# How to stop component re-rendering between pages in React, Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, memoization

I have a particular component for the home page of my application that has a cool css animation to change colors. It goes through 3 colors for a total of 120s.

Though I have a problem... Whenever I go to another page, for example I go to the /blog path and then decide to go back to the home page this component will start its animation from the beginning.

Since its a 100vw 100vh component Its quite obvious that it re-renders.
My idea is to make it so that it doesn't re-render at all and the animation is always running in the background no matter which page you are on.

I tried to wrap it with React.memo, but that didn't work.
I'm open to ideas and would appreciate any feedback.
Thank you!

Comment: Very interesting question. I managed to find this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60241167/12485722 hope it gives you an idea.

Comment: You need to persist `Animation.currentTime` between pages. You can use the context API or maybe some state management library like redux, recoil, zustand to persist that.

Comment: what about mapping the animation with time i.e. animation-time = (time-passed)/(total-time) . And store the progress in global state and whenever the page reloads starts the animation from where it lefts. After time reaches to total-time set the animation-time = 0.